# Error subclassing QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qtreewidget

I am getting a mysterious error trying to subclass QTreeWidget. Below is code from the relevant files. In QtDesigner, I have promoted a QTreeWidget to a treeWidget, but I get the following error:

Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'treeWidget' Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hw2\QTOpenGL\GeneratedFiles\ui_opengldemo.h 72  1   QTOpenGL

I have been told not to edit code in the ui_ files, so I'm assuming this problem can be solved without going in there. Any ideas? Does the code below give enough information to solve this issue? Thanks.

```
**treeWidget.h:**

#ifndef TREEWIDGET
#define TREEWIDGET

#include <QTreeWidget>
#include "gNode.h"
class treeWidget :
    public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    treeWidget(QWidget*);
    ~treeWidget(void);
public slots:
    void topLevelItem(gNode* node);
};

#endif


**treeWidget.cpp**
#include "treeWidget.h"


treeWidget::treeWidget(QWidget* parent) : QTreeWidget(parent)
{
}


treeWidget::~treeWidget(void)
{
}

void treeWidget::topLevelItem(gNode* node){
    addTopLevelItem(node);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message ?

Comment: I did. That's pretty much all it says. This message is repeated verbatim three times referencing the same line number. 1>C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hw2\QTOpenGL\GeneratedFiles\ui_opengldemo.h(72): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'treeWidget'
1>  opengldemo.cpp

Comment: The `ui_` header files usually come from using the Qt designer to make the GUI. You are referencing treeWidget in the GUI, so the problem probably lies there.

Comment: When promoting the QTreeWidget in the designer, did you give it the right path to `treeWidget.h`?

Comment: the topLevelItem is not virtual.

Comment: cbamber85: yes, i did that in the "promote" dialog. neox: i tried declaring the topLevelItem(gNode*) function as virtual in the .h file, and I received the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Changed name to myTreeWidget from treeWidget and all works fine.